# Insert a space between a numerical number and character

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have an mathematical equation

```
var equation="(4+5.5)*3+4.5+4.2";
```

When i do

```
equation.split('').join(' ');
```

It gets output, space between each character.

```
( 4 + 5 . 5 ) * 3 + 4 . 5 + 4 . 2
```

How to do insert a space between numerical number and alpha character?

Sample Output :

```
( 4  +  5.5 ) *  3  +  4.5  +  4.2
```

Have anyone can help me how to figure out, thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no alpha character ..

Comment: Rather than adding a space between every character, you might be better looking explicitly for non-numeric characters and spacing these instead.

Comment: try this: `"(4+5.5)*3+4.5+4.2".replace(/[+\-*/]/g, ' $& ');`

Comment: @mojtabaramezani: note that the OP wants parentheses to be spaced as well.

Comment: Is scientific notation allowed in your equations, like `2e-5+2e+5`?

Comment: @georg no at that moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pad the operators.

```js
var string = "(4+5.5)*3+4.5+4.2",
    result = string.replace(/[+\-*/]/g, ' $& ');

console.log(result);
```

Parentheses with spaces.

```js
var string = "(4+5.5)*3+4.5+-4.2",
    result = string
        .replace(/[+\-*/()]/g, ' $& ')
        .replace(/([+\-*/]\s+[+\-])\s+/, '$1')
        .replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You need to account for brackets in your regex as well - /[+\-*/()]/g

Answer (score 2):

You might use a regular expression and match either numeric tokens (digits, optionally followed by a period and other digits), or match any character. Then, join by a space:

```js
const equation = "(4+5.5)*3+4.5+4.2";
const output = equation
  .match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?|./g)
  .join(' ');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to make the group optional, should work now